# Mark second location in a repeating pattern

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers below which has a repeating pattern (usually 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 before starting over again, but sometimes one or more will not be in there due to holidays, etc). I want to mark the second occurrence in each of these sets (usually 3 but not always if for example 2 isnt there it would be 4 that I want marked). Any ideas how to flag what essentially is the 2nd business day of a week?

code example:

```
test_vector <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
inds <- which(c(TRUE, diff(test_vector) != 1L) & #find start of week
              c(TRUE, diff(test_vector[-1]) == 1L, FALSE) #protect against one-day weeks
              ) + 1L
test_vector[inds]
#[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4
```

Comment: Nicely done using base R and the protection against one day weeks is nice too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you what as far as a flag, but this will let you know where that value exists.

```
for(i in 1:length(unique(test_vector))){
print(paste0(unique(test_vector)[i], " at position ", which(test_vector == unique(test_vector)[i])[2]))
}
```

To see the next sets you would change the [2] to 4 or 6 or 8 or however many sets you have.